# How does Django turn field name strings to field name variables?

Tags: python, duck-typing

I'm very new to python and (coming from Java) am trying to think in a "pythonic" way. I'm having trouble understanding how Django turns a function (or variable) name given in string to the actual function.

Example from Django tutorial: If we give:

```
list_display = ('question', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')
```

Django reads the function and some related properties from the code:

```
def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
```

**So, my question: How does the string get turned into the actual function name?**

Comment: many interpreted languages model objects as associative arrays with strings as keys and the members and functions as values

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488155/call-a-method-of-an-object-with-arguments-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python has numerous ways to turn strings into objects. The most important are:

- Attribute access with [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), allowing you to translate `foo.bar` into `getattr(foo, 'bar')`.
- Dictionary access, `mapping[key]`. Almost anything in Python can be reduced to dictionaries; by default class instances store information in a mapping called `__dict__` for example, so `instance.__dict__[key]` works in many cases. Module namespaces use a mapping like that too.

  The built-in functions [`vars()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars), [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) and [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) all return a namespace mapping.

If you are interested in Python introspection, you may want to study the [Python datamodel](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), and take a look at the [`inspect` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) as well.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. I love concise answers :)